# Programmatically set FBSDKAccessToken

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'd like to be able to use the Facebook SDK inside iOS, but I want to grab the authentication token manually so as not to require the user to login.  How can I use the SDK to grab a token like I would the following with basic REST?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
grant_type=client_credentials
```

My sense tells me that I can use `FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken()` to set the `currentAccessToken` for the scope such that calls to `FBSDKGraphRequest` work as expected.

But formatting the permissions array and other calls are a bit elusive.  My primary use case for this is to grab public feeds like this graph path `patagonia/feed`.

Comment: see my answer you helped

Comment: Have you tried just setting the token, and checking the permissions and other properties once you've done so? You may need to call `refreshCurrentAccessToken:` and wait for the completion handler to be called to get up-to-date data. Note that you should NOT use app access tokens, as this would require either the access token or the app secret to be embedded in your app, which is very strongly advised against. You may use a "client token" instead (found in your Facebook app's dashboard).